# How to loop all properties from object passed as parameter and change their values?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties, iteration

I'm passing in an object like:

```
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

I am trying to change `1/2/3` to `changed`

Here is my code:

```
var func = function(change) {
  for (var property in change) {
    if (func.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      change.property = "changed"
      return func
    }
  }
}
```

Right now my output is giving me the original properties with no change.
I tried returning `func` inside the if statement to see if this was a scope problem but no luck.

Comment: It's not clear what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: I think you mean **argument**, not property

Comment: _Loop through all the properties on the func object..._ Your code does different: loop through the properties of the 1st func's argument

Comment: `change.property` doesn't make sense in your case since it refers to undefined property. You have to use bracket notation instead: `change[property] = ...`

Comment: i think you should check property in `change` instead in `func` in if-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to loop all properties from object you pass as parameter and change their values to "changed"

```
function func(change) {
  Object.keys(change).forEach(function(key) {
    change[key] = 'changed';
  });
};
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
func(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Your function doesn't need `return` because you are changing object values passed by reference.

Comment: I am using return to check that my output is correct. And this worked perfectly! I think I was making everything to complicated, and I did not know about "forEach"

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the misleading wording. I'm familiar with Ruby but JS seems a bit archaic to me still.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. Your variable will not work as part of '.' notation. You must use brackets to accomplish this.

```
var func = function(change){
  for (var property in change) {
    if (func.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      func[property] = "changed"
    }
  }
  return func
}
```

Comment: What type the `change` do you think is?

Comment: I have no idea, it just seemed like he was trying to set the variable to a property name on an object. I could be way off :p

Comment: "I have no idea" --- and then you are suggesting to use it as a property name. Do you think it makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to change all `argumetns`

```
var func = function(){
  for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) 
      arguments[i]='changed'
  return arguments;
}
```

For example:

```
 func('a',b'c') // return ['changed','changed','changed']
```